# Why does a shifted integer mask with a tilde casted to a long return zero? (Java, bit shift)

Tags: java, long-integer, bit-shift, bitmask, tilde

I am trying to create a mask to view specific bits on a long in Java. I tried the following:

```
long mask = ~ (0xffffffff << 32);
```

If I print this on the console it will return 0 but I am expecting 4294967295 since my result should look like 0x00000000FFFFFFFFL and 2^32 - 1 equals 4294967295. When I shift a long mask it works but I do not understand why.

```
long mask = ~ (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL << 32);
```

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

Comment: When you do `int << int` you get an `int` not a long in the same way that `int * int` is still an `int`. You need to do `long << int` if you want a `long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java assumes that if you're performing arithmetic operations on `ints`, then you want to get an `int` back, not a `long`. (The fact that you assign the output to a `long` after the calculation is done does not affect the calculation itself.)

Left-shifting an `int` (which is 32 bits) by 32 places does nothing. When you left-shift an `int`, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used, giving a number in the range 0 to 31.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19

That's why `(0xffffffff<<32)==0xffffffff`, and `~(0xffffffff<<32)==0`

When shifting a `long` (which is 64 bits), the six lowest-order bits are used, giving a number in the range 0 to 63.

If you use `0xffffffffL`, then Java will know to produce another `long`. So you can shift by 32 places without going off the left end of the number.

Comment: Okay now I understand. I just tried long mask = ~ ((long) 0xffffffff << 32); and it works.

Comment: "leaving all the int bits as zero"  but then they  `~` it, so, explain why it is still 0

Comment: The casting happens after the operation is performed so you can view this as a two step process :-
int intmask = ~ (0xffffffff << 32);
long mask= intmask;

Answer (score 1):

Left shift is modulus† the size of the data type, e.g. a shift of an int of 32 bits has no effect.

```
(0xffffffff << 32) ==
(0xffffffff << (32 % Integer.SIZE)) ==
(0xffffffff << (32 % 32)) ==
(0xffffffff << 0) ==
0xffffffff
```

And `~` of `0xffffffff` is `0x00000000`, i.e. `0` which is what you see.

Then with 64 bit, the full 32 bit shift is applied as it is less than 64:

```
(0xffffffffL << 32) ==
(0xffffffffL << (32 % Long.SIZE) ==
(0xffffffffL << (32 % 64) ==
(0xffffffffL << 32) ==
0xffffffff00000000L
```

† Strictly speaking it's taking the last 5 bits for ints and last 6 for longs, which makes a difference over modulus for negative left shifts.